# I am facing issue while running "mvn clean install" while connecting AEM with react

Tags: aem, single-page-application, aem-6

i am following the tutorial https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kt/sites/using/getting-started-spa-wknd-tutorial-develop/react/chapter-0.html#integrate-react-app for integrating reactjs with AEM,i am facing issue while running "mvn clean install" and i was able to perform previous steps properly.

```
C:\Users\TEJA\Desktop\Start-aem-wknd-events-react\Start\aem-guides-wknd-events\react-app>mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------< com.adobe.aem.guides:aem-guides-wknd-events.react >----------
[INFO] Building WKND Events - React App 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ aem-guides-wknd-events.react ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-maven) @ aem-guides-wknd-events.react ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) @ aem-guides-wknd-events.react ---
[INFO] Installing node version v10.8.0
[INFO] Copying node binary from C:\Users\TEJA\.m2\repository\com\github\eirslett\node\10.8.0\node-10.8.0-win-x64.exe to C:\Users\TEJA\Desktop\Start-aem-wknd-events-react\Start\aem-guides-wknd-events\react-app\node\node.exe
[INFO] Installed node locally.
[INFO] NPM 6.2.0 is already installed.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:npm (npm install) @ aem-guides-wknd-events.react ---
[INFO] Running 'npm install' in C:\Users\TEJA\Desktop\Start-aem-wknd-events-react\Start\aem-guides-wknd-events\react-app
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.810 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-20T23:44:11+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:npm (npm install) on project aem-guides-wknd-events.react: Failed to run task: 'npm install' failed. java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\TEJA\Desktop\Start-aem-wknd-events-react\Start\aem-guides-wknd-events\react-app\node\node.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\TEJA\Desktop\Start-aem-wknd-events-react\Start\aem-guides-wknd-events\react-app"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

C:\Users\TEJA\Desktop\Start-aem-wknd-events-react\Start\aem-guides-wknd-events\react-app>npm install aem-clientlib-generator --save-dev
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ aem-clientlib-generator@1.4.4
updated 1 package and audited 33138 packages in 31.111s
found 1041 vulnerabilities (71 low, 8 moderate, 960 high, 2 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

C:\Users\TEJA\Desktop\Start-aem-wknd-events-react\Start\aem-guides-wknd-events\react-app>mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------< com.adobe.aem.guides:aem-guides-wknd-events.react >----------
[INFO] Building WKND Events - React App 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ aem-guides-wknd-events.react ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-maven) @ aem-guides-wknd-events.react ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) @ aem-guides-wknd-events.react ---
[INFO] Installing node version v10.8.0
[INFO] Copying node binary from C:\Users\TEJA\.m2\repository\com\github\eirslett\node\10.8.0\node-10.8.0-win-x64.exe to C:\Users\TEJA\Desktop\Start-aem-wknd-events-react\Start\aem-guides-wknd-events\react-app\node\node.exe
[INFO] Installed node locally.
[INFO] NPM 6.2.0 is already installed.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:npm (npm install) @ aem-guides-wknd-events.react ---
[INFO] Running 'npm install' in C:\Users\TEJA\Desktop\Start-aem-wknd-events-react\Start\aem-guides-wknd-events\react-app
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.590 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-20T23:45:29+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:npm (npm install) on project aem-guides-wknd-events.react: Failed to run task: 'npm install' failed. java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\TEJA\Desktop\Start-aem-wknd-events-react\Start\aem-guides-wknd-events\react-app\node\node.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\TEJA\Desktop\Start-aem-wknd-events-react\Start\aem-guides-wknd-events\react-app"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

C:\Users\TEJA\Desktop\Start-aem-wknd-events-react\Start\aem-guides-wknd-events\react-app>mvn clean install
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used `frontend-maven-plugin` without issues in other projects, by reading the error message, it seems it is common that the `npm.exe` executable gets corrupted.

Try deleting your `.m2` plugin directory or specifying a custom npm version `<npmVersions>`.

See [issue 487 on GitHub](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/issues/487)

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be in the script in one of the react/webpack config files. Search for "%1" in the directory, %1 may be passed as a parameter in the script/command

> %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Usually these are linux commands and will fail to work in windows machines. Can you try installing this in a linux machine?